# Unable to save a matplotlib plot via docker

Tags: docker, matplotlib

I am trying to save a figure to my local after I build and run my docker file.
My docker File is this

```
FROM python:3.7   
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
    
    # copy all the files to the container  
COPY . .  
RUN mkdir -p /root/.config/matplotlib  
RUN echo "backend : Agg" > /root/.config/matplotlib/matplotlibrc
    
RUN pip install pandas matplotlib==2.2.4
    
CMD ["python", "./main.py"]
```

My main.py is this

```
import matplotlib

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data/coding-environment-exercise.csv')
st_name=data['student']
marks=data['mark']
x=list(st_name)
y=list(marks)
print(x)
out_path = '/output/your_filename.png'
plt.plot(x,y)

plt.savefig("test2.png",format="png")
```

However after I run this docker file via these commands I can't find the png. It tried my code in local python ide. It saves the figure however I couldn't do it via docker.

```
docker build -t plot:docker . 
docker run -it plot:docker
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Docker container has it's own separate file system from the host running the container. In order to obtain the image from the host you must mount a so called volume within the container which you can do using the `-v` option. You must mount the directory which should contain your image.

```bash
docker run -it -v /path/on/host:/path/in/container plot:docker
```

Please see the [Docker documentation on volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for more details.

Another option to obtain the image is the use of the [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) command as long as the container is not yet removed which allows you to copy files from within the container to the host (and the other way round).

```bash
docker cp <container-name>:/path/to/file/in/container.png /target/path/on/host.png
```

You can set the container name using the `--name` flag in the `docker run` commmand.

```bash
docker run --name my-container -it plot:docker
```

Comment: I used docker cp to copy my png to my local and it worked like a charm! Thanks!